# Word2vec - KeyError

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec

I trained a word2vec from the gensim package. Even though I pass a word in the model.train() method, it doesnt appear in the model's vocab.

1. Can such a case arise?
2. Why does it happen so?

Comment: Will you, please provide a detail description of error, plus the code? It will help in sorting it out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is the default value for min_count is 5 in word2vec. Since my words have very less frequency, they are not being added to the vocabulary.

Comment: Seems you resolved it at your own. Is it? If yes, then update the answer, it will help other. Cheers!